# Replace a "Tag" ( string ) with all the matches in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, logic, frontend

I am trying to permute a string that comes as follows  to its possible values.

I have an object with the following format

```js
{
  descriptions: ["Here's some <tag> exemple", "Can be something without Tag"],
  headlines: ["<tag> another exemple", "<tag>"]
}
```

I have an array with different permutations for the

```js
["First","Second","Third"]
```

I am trying to create as much objects as the permutation to get this result at the end

```js
[
  {
    descriptions: ["Here's some First exemple", "Can be something without Tag"],
    headlines: ["First another exemple", "First"]
  },
  {
    descriptions: [
      "Here's some Second exemple",
      "Can be something without Tag"
    ],
    headlines: ["Second another exemple", "Second"]
  },
  {
    descriptions: ["Here's some Third exemple", "Can be something without Tag"],
    headlines: ["Third another exemple", "Third"]
  }
];
```

I'm stuck here ..

```js
function foo(adCopy: AdCopy[], tag: string, variants: string[]) {
  variants.forEach(variant => {
    adCopy.forEach(adCopy => {
      adCopy.headlines.map(headline => {

      })
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const mapObj = (obj, map) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(map));

const result = variants.map(variant =>
   adCopies.map(adCopy =>
     mapObj(adCopy, ([key, values]) => ([
        key, 
        values.map(value => value.replace(/<tag>/, variant))
     ]))
   )
);
```

You can *map* all variabts to their permutations, and you can use `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.entries` to map objects.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to modify your original object, you can do this:

```js
let obj = {
 descriptions: ["Here's some <tag> exemple", "Can be something without Tag"],
 headlines: ["<tag> another exemple", "<tag>"]
};
let permutations = ['First', 'Second', 'Third'];

let objMapped = permutations.map(permutation =>
 Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, values]) => {
  acc[key] = values.map(value => value.replace(/<tag>/g, permutation));
  return acc;
 }, {}));

console.log(objMapped);
```